# The images in my navigation bar fall below each other when I close the browser window instead of simply disappearing.. Why?

Tags: html, css, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

My html is pretty simple:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <li><a id="button" href="#" <img src=""></a></li>
    <li><a id="button2"  href="#" <img src=""></a></li>
    <li><a id="button3"  href="#" <img src=""></a></li>
</div>
```

And my css is:

```
.navigation {
margin-top:35px;
margin-left: -290px;
list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation li{
display: inline;
}

#button, #button2, #button3 {

-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
padding: 30px;
float: left;
margin-left: 390px;
}

#button{
 background-image: url("../images/homebutton.png");
}
#button2 {
background-image: url("../images/gmailbutton.png");
background-repeat: no repeat;
}
#button3 {
background-image: url("../images/blogbutton.png");
}
```

Now it looks fine when the browser window is open, but when I close the window the images start stacking vertically instead of just disappearing when the window rolls over.  Any ideas??? Thanks :)

Comment: Well, with invalid HTML you should expect a faulty implementation: an `li` is the only valid child of a `ul` or `ol`, and those are the only elements in which an `li` may be found. They are *not* valid within a `div` element.

Comment: Your <a> tags are malformed. Should be <a><img /></a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you change the `.navigation` element to be a `ul` or `ol` (validity is important), then you can simply add: `white-space: nowrap;` to force the elements to all appear on one line, instead of wrapping (as an `inline` element naturally will, and should):

```
.navigation {
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-left: -290px;
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M9YNw/).

And please note the corrected `a` and `img` tags.

Comment: Hey thanks, I had to take float: left off of the buttons too.  Thanks again.  :-)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to have been of help (and, I must confess, I completely missed the `float` property...oops).